# extract from a multiple json

Tags: java, json

I have a json like this:

```
[{"id":"****","value":"*****","date":"****"},
{"id":"****","value":"*****","date":"****"},
{"id":"****","value":"*****","date":"****"},
{"id":"****","value":"*****","date":"****"}]
```

every "sub-json" I want to convert it to Model object.(an object that contains as attributes id value and date).
How can I do it?
Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this link. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got an array of objects.

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
   String id = jsonobject.getString("id");
   String value = jsonobject.getString("value");
}
```